Property 'object' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'type' is not assignable to type 'never'
Hello i have trouble when i build my next js app. it says
.next/types/app/(dashboard)/approval/view/page.ts:28:13

Property 'surat' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'SuratApprovalType' is not assignable to type 'never'

i have narrowed of files that might be causing this type
this is my component that got error
src\app(dashboard)\approval\view\page.tsx
type SuratApprovalType = {
  file: string;
  tipeSurat: string;
  judul: string;
  status: string;
  suratId: string;
  userId: string;
}

interface DocViewApprovalProps {
  surat: SuratApprovalType;
  suratId: string;
}

function DocViewApproval({ surat, suratId }: DocViewApprovalProps) // this line cause error because my props cause Type Error when i run build
 { return(<p className="text-black"> testing </p>)
}

export default DocViewApproval;

this is the page that use the component above
src\app(dashboard)\approval\components\dialog.tsx
import { DialogContent } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { user } from "@/signals/userSignal";
import DocViewApproval from "../view/page";
import { useSignals } from "@preact/signals-react/runtime";
const domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_URL;

interface Props {
  suratId: string | undefined | null;
}

type SuratApprovalType = {
  file: string;
  tipeSurat: string;
  judul: string;
  status: string;
  suratId: string;
  userId: string;
}

type Data = {
  file: string;
  tipeSurat: string;
  judul: string;
  status: string;
}

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export function LogDialog({ suratId }: Props) {
  useSignals()
  const userId: string | undefined = user.value?.id;
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR<Data>(
    suratId ? `${domain}/api/surat/getSuratList?id=${suratId}` : null,
    fetcher
  );

  if (isLoading) return <p className="text-black">Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p className="text-black">Failed to load surat data</p>;

  if (data && userId && suratId) {
    const surat:SuratApprovalType = { ...data, suratId, userId };
    return (
      <DialogContent className="flex flex-col w-[95%] text-black h-[90%]">
        {surat !== null ? (
          <DocViewApproval surat={surat} suratId={suratId} /> // this line related to my props in DocsViewApproval
        ) : (
          <div>Surat not found.</div>
        )}
      </DialogContent>
    );
  }
}

as far i can do to solve the problem is to delete the props of DocViewApproval({ surat, suratId }: DocViewApprovalProps) and the error wont show again but obviously it is not the solution im looking for. can someone point out what im doing wrong?
thanks

On what line are you getting the error exactly? Why does DocViewApproval not actually use its props somewhere?

i edited my code snippet to show what line that might cause the error. i think as long im send props to DocViewApproval it will trigger the error. As for DocViewApproval props, actually it use its props but i edited my real code to simplify the code snippet because the error still exist when i build it with just the code i provide above
